# Swing Timer Compilation Error

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm in the process of creating a little application for school that counts down the time that you entered into the jTextField. I haven't gotten that far yet because as I was creating the Swing Timer, I got a couple of errors that I cant figure out. I've Googled with out any luck.

Here's my code.

```
    package randomGUIs;

    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Timer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

       String time;
       Timer countDownTimer;

    public Timer() {
       initComponents();

    ActionListener downTime = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            jLabel1.setText(time);

        }
    };

    int countdown = 1000;
    countDownTimer = new Timer(countdown, downTime);
    countDownTimer.setRepeats(true);

};
```

The error that I'm getting

error: randomGUIs.Timer is already defined in this compilation unit
import javax.swing.Timer;

I'm Using Netbeans and have tried unchecking the "Compile on save option" with out luck

Comment: why do you use Timer as name of the class

Comment: Is that bad? Just the name I chose I guess.

Comment: of course don't use it .just rename to Timer1 or anything

Comment: Jeez, I feel stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give your public class a name different than `Timer` since it is conflicting with `javax.swing.Timer`.